# Why use a generic method with a type constraint instead of the type itself?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

In a different StackExchange question, I noticed someone using this prototype:

```
void DoSomething<T>(T arg) where T: SomeSpecificReferenceType
{
    //Code....
}
```

Bearing in mind there is only a single type constraint (`SomeSpecificReferenceType`), what is the difference and advantage of writing it like that, instead of simply:

```
void DoSomething(SomeSpecificReferenceType arg)
{
    //Code....
}
```

In both cases, `arg` will be subject to compile-time type checking.  In both cases, the body of the method can safely rely on knowledge that `arg` is of (or is a descendant of) a specific type that is known at compile time.

Is this a case of an overzealous developer learning about generics before learning about ordinary inheritance? Or is there a legitimate reason why a method signature would be written this way?

Comment: I barely know C# so this is only a guess, but doesn't this enable more efficient static dispatch instead of dynamic dispatch?

Answer (score 13):

> Is this a case of an overzealous developer learning about generics before learning about ordinary inheritance?

Yes, it probably is.

> Or is there a legitimate reason why a method signature would be written this way?

*Maybe*. Generally, it'd make more sense if there was a return value that involved `T`, or another parameter that used `T`.

But, it's possible that the internals of the code use `T` (perhaps as an argument to a serializer?) and *need* to use specifically `T` and not the constraint class. You'll occasionally see that when the constraint is an interface paired with the `new` constraint and the guts of the method creates `T`s for some reason.

So while it's rare to see the constraint version needed, there are some times when it is. And it's always possible that the method *used* to need it, but now does not and the developer left it as is to not introduce a breaking change.

Answer (score 1):

I think I remember myself typing an answer containing this.

At that time the reason was like this:
*(The code may be different. Just to illustrate one of the possible reasons why there's a constraint on the type parameter in a generic method.)*

```
class SomeSingleton
{
    static Dictionary<Type, List<object>> staticTypeSpecificList;
    public void AddObjectToList<T>(T t) where T : SomeCommonThing
    {
        Type tt = t.GetType();
        List<object> list;
        if (!staticTypeSpecificList.TryGet(tt, out list))
        {
            list = new List<object>();
            staticTypeSpecificList.Add(tt, list);
        }
        list.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Basically, the code gets into manually coding type manipulations itself. It might also be mixed up with some reflection stuff.

For example, by using `Method<T>(T arg) where T : ...`, one can replace `arg.GetType()` with `typeof(T)`. Though, I don't know whether that choice is good or bad.

I guess this is just an example of the author (possibly me, or someone else) **not carefully thinking through all of the possibilities** of coding, at the same time focusing too much on a different question/issue.

Comment: "one can replace arg.GetType() with typeof(T)". This is useful when arg can validly be null, E.g. in some serialization cases.